# PHPunit tests on Laravel routes always returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-7

I just began writing PHPUnit route tests on my laravel application and it's working fine via browser and Postman, not via PHPunit though.

Example: on this test

```
public function test_getAll(){
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling(); // If i comment this line I get the 404 and not the error shown below

    $response = $this->get('/api/users');
    $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

I get:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.E                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 1.89 seconds, Memory: 8.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\Users\UserRoute_SuperAdminTest::test_getAll
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: GET http://localhost/cms/api/users

E:\www\projects\cms-php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithExceptionHandling.php:126
E:\www\projects\cms-php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:415
E:\www\projects\cms-php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:113
E:\www\projects\cms-php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:468
E:\www\projects\cms-php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:258
E:\www\projects\cms-php\tests\Feature\Users\UsersRoute-SuperAdmin_Test.php:45
```

The weird thing is: if i change the URL to:

```
$response = $this->get('http://anythingatallinhere/api/users');
```

I get the 401 response that I should.

More context info to solve the problem.

My env APP_URL is `APP_URL=http://localhost/cms` and I am registering routes dynamically this way: I have a CoreServiceProvider with a boot procedure like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
       [...]
        $moduleController = app()->make(ModuleController::class);
        $moduleController->registerCoreRoutes();
       [...]
    }
```

on ModuleController:

```
function registerCoreRoutes(){
        foreach($this->allValidated as $moduleAlias => $registeredModule){
            $modName = ucfirst(str_replace('core/', '', strtolower($moduleAlias)));
            $namespace = 'App\Api\Core' . '\\' . $modName . '\Controllers';

            try {
                foreach ($registeredModule['routerFiles'] as $key => $routerInfo){
                    $routePath = app_path('Api/Core/' . $modName . '/Routes/' . $routerInfo['fileName'] . '.php');
                    $prefix = 'api/' . $routerInfo['path'];

                    $this->pathToModule[$routerInfo['path']] = $moduleAlias;

                    Route::prefix($prefix)
                        ->namespace($namespace)
                        ->group($routePath);
                }
                $this->allRegistered[$moduleAlias] = $registeredModule;
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                var_dump('Core module route registration failed');
                $this->allRegistered = [];
                throw $th;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I use `php artisan route:list` they are all there properly registered as well.

Comment: Try this `$response = $this->get('api/users');`

Comment: Already tried all URL combinations that came in my mind, this included. I get the same thing

Comment: what are the full results for the relevant row in routes:list ? What happens if you resolve the route from the name and use that in the test, e.g. dump(route('api.users')); $this->get(route('api.users'));

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper it's too big to post as an answer so I'll post the first 2: 
`|        | GET|HEAD | api/users   | users.list   |  App\Api\Core\User\Controllers\UserController@getAll | authjwt,getUserResource,can:read   | | 
| PUT      | api/users/editbasic/{id}    | users.editBasic             | App\Api\Core\User\Controllers\UserController@editBasicInfo        | authjwt,getUserResource,can:update |`

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I did what you mentioned right after and still is returning the same error: 

`dump(route('users.list'));
        
$response = $this->get(route('users.list'));`
.
`PHPUnit 8.5.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.E                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)"http://localhost/cms/api/users"


Time: 2.2 seconds, Memory: 8.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\Users\UserRoute_SuperAdminTest::test_getAll
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: GET http://localhost/cms/api/users`

Comment: If I do only a `dd(route('users.list')` it returns 
`1) Tests\Feature\Users\UserRoute_SuperAdminTest::test_getAll
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: "http://localhost/cms/api/users"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently but it worked after running these:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Especially if you changed the just changed the APP_URL in your .env file.

You could also try setting `processIsolation` to `true` in your phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
 backupStaticAttributes="false"
 bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
 colors="true"
 convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
 convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
 convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
 processIsolation="true"
 stopOnFailure="false">
```

**EDIT:**
If none of the above works, you could also create another `.env.testing` and set your `APP_URL` to `http://localhost`.
PHPUnit will use variables from that file. This works regardless of the actual URL of your application

Comment: Hey, @Clement Sam. Thanks for the answer. Already tried it. Tried those and `php artisan route:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` as well

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an alternative solution I normally work with

Comment: You could also create another `.env.testing` and set your `APP_URL` to `http://localhost`. PHPUnit will use variables from that file. This works regardless of the actual URL of your application

Comment: I already had the `processIsolation="true"` as I looked for countless solutions on stack overflow. Also I already had a `.env.testing` file with `APP_URL` set to `http://localhost/cms`. Changing it to `http://localhost` did the trick though. Now it's working properly. Since the `/cms` is part of the url, do you have any idea why it only works without it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set APP_URL to `http://localhost` in the `phpunit.xml` file by adding this line:

```
<server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>
```

This method is best if you want to the variables in `.env` to still be available during testing. Creating your own `.env.testing` file will override all `.env` variables.